# How to use Azure App Service /web aliases?

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, azure-policy

When I look through to [documentation](https://github.com/Azure/azure-policy/blob/1c687fcbff5b58e1eff7654d562ff23c201a1910/README.md) there's mention of the `Microsoft.Web/sites/config/web` aliases but it is not clear when they are evaluated.

I have created the policy below and it is working correctly. Is there a reason why I should also configure it to check the `Microsoft.Web/sites/config/web.localMySqlEnabled` alias?

Example of similar aliases

- Microsoft.Web/sites/config/localMySqlEnabled
- Microsoft.Web/sites/config/web.localMySqlEnabled

Policy Rule

```
  "policyRule": {
    "if": {
      "allOf": [
        {
          "field": "type",
          "equals": "Microsoft.Web/sites/config"
        },
        {
          "field": "name",
          "equals": "web"
        },
        {
          "field": "Microsoft.Web/sites/config/localMySqlEnabled",
          "exists": "true"
        },
        {
          "field": "Microsoft.Web/sites/config/localMySqlEnabled",
          "notEquals": "false"
        }
      ]
    },
    "then": {
      "effect": "Deny"
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason that some resource properties have multiple aliases is because of changes in convention internally when creating aliases. We usually recommend using both since it won't affect the policy. But as your said, it should work with one.